# Why is this Maps code not working?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've got all the locations and it the choords. It must be some little something I'm doing wrong in the code. Anyone see anything wrong? Basically I'm trying to make a map with multiple pins and I'm not quite sure what's causing this one not to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Kapten Nemo', 57.707957,11.934296, 4],
      ['Slimfood', 57.712283,11.944914, 5],
      ['L's Kitchen', 57.707126,11.939796, 3],
      ['Bombay Bistro', 57.708316,11.937755, 2],
      ['Mimolett', 57.712283,11.944914, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.72, 11.94),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: in your locations the array object ['L's Kitchen', 57.707126,11.939796, 3], has an apostrophe in L's which could be messing with your array. You should use 'L\'s Kitchen

Comment: SEE! I kneew it was something little and stupid I was doing xD. Thanks a ton mate my brain must be fried.

Comment: No problem, sometimes another pair of eyes are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it turned out that the apostrophe in L's Kitchen was the issue.

```
...
['L\'s Kitchen', 57.707126,11.939796, 3],
...
```

Here it is in http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/NGmLY/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 ['L's Kitchen', 57.707126,11.939796, 3],
```

To

```
 ["L's Kitchen", 57.707126,11.939796, 3],
```